# Is it possible to combine agg and value_counts in single line with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a `df`

```
   a  b  ngroup
0  1  3       0
1  1  4       0
2  1  1       0
3  3  7       2
4  4  4       2
5  1  1       4
6  2  2       4
7  1  1       4
8  6  6       5
```

I would like to compute the summation of multiple columns (i.e., `a` and `b`) grouped by the column `ngroup`.

In addition, I would like to count the number of element for each of the group.

Based on these two condition, the expected output as below

```
a   b   nrow_same_group ngroup
3   8   3               0
7   11  2               2
4   4   3               4
6   6   1               5
```

The following code should do the work

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip([1,1,1,3,4,1,2,1,6,10],
                         [3,4,1,7,4,1,2,1,6,1],
                         [0,0,0,2,2,4,4,4,5])),columns=['a','b','ngroup'])


grouped_df = df.groupby(['ngroup'])
df1 = grouped_df[['a','b']].agg('sum').reset_index()


df2 = df['ngroup'].value_counts().reset_index()

df2.sort_values('index', axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={'index':'ngroup','ngroup':'nrow_same_group'},inplace=True)
df= pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['ngroup'])
```

However, I wonder whether there exist `built-in` pandas that achieve something similar, in single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First aggregate `a, b` with `sum` then calculate `size` of each group and assign this to `nrow_same_group` column

```
g = df.groupby('ngroup')
g.sum().assign(nrow_same_group=g.size())
```

---

```
        a   b  nrow_same_group
ngroup                        
0       3   8                3
2       7  11                2
4       4   4                3
5       6   6                1
```

Comment: @rpb We are not using `unstack` here.

Comment: @rpb I see, you can simply reset the index `g.sum().assign(nrow_same_group=g.size()).reset_index()`

Comment: For Future reader>> `g = df.groupby('ngroup')
t=g.sum().assign(nrow_same_group=g.size()).reset_index()`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using only `groupby` + [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html).

```
import pandas as pd 

df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip([1,1,1,3,4,1,2,1,6,10],
                         [3,4,1,7,4,1,2,1,6,1],
                         [0,0,0,2,2,4,4,4,5])),columns=['a','b','ngroup'])

res = (
    df.groupby('ngroup', as_index=False)
      .agg(a=('a','sum'), b=('b', 'sum'), 
           nrow_same_group=('a', 'size'))
)
```

Here the parameters passed to `agg` are tuples whose first element is the column to aggregate and the second element is the aggregation function to apply to that column. The parameter names are the labels for the resulting columns.

Output:

```
>>> res

   ngroup  a   b  nrow_same_group
0       0  3   8                3
1       2  7  11                2
2       4  4   4                3
3       5  6   6                1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful for a limited number of columns